# Use java to perform binary shifts

Tags: java, binary, xor, shift

I have to take a binary data in java and perform shifts on it.
For e.g. 11110000 when I right shift it by 2 , i.e. 11110000>>00111100

The problem is that, I don't know how to store such a data in Java, as the byte type converts it to decimal format. I need to use the bit at position 6 and XOR it with some other value.

I just need to know how I can achieve the ability to store binary data and perform the required shifts.

Comment: Google it man there's thousands of guides/tutorials

Comment: just use `int`s or `long`s or some other numeric datatype. The number will still appear in base 10, but the numbers are internally base 2, so bit manipulation will work with those datatypes.

Comment: Just do it. And you will see the result.  It will appear in proper form for it's type, but why does it matter?  Shift happens anyway.  And when you tried, you can come back here with questions showing your code and the result.  Otherwise, you'll be just collecting downvotes.

Comment: The phrase "the byte type converts it to decimal format" makes no sense whatsoever.  A `byte` is a number without a format; it's only how you read in or out a number that makes it binary or decimal or whatever.

Comment: [regarding the edit] The question is closed anyway, you can just leave it like this. If you really need to delete the question, then you should _flag_ it, choose _other_ and explain why you want to delete it to a moderator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using an integer it'll display it in a number format, you can work around it using `Integer.toBinaryString(yourByte)`

Second, if you're using an integer to store a binary number in the format of `1...` (the leftmost bit is 1) then using the operation `>>` will shift the number right but enter a "new" `1` into the leftmost bit. What you want to do in such case is actually use `>>>` which prevents that.

If you're using an `int` to store your byte, and you want to start doing all kind of bit manipulations than you'll have to use a `mask`, for example, switching between the 3rd and the 5th bits:

```
    int number = 7; //just an example, here binary rep: 00111 => requested output will be 10011
    System.out.println("number = " + Integer.toBinaryString(number));
    int mask3Bit = 4;//binary rep: 0100
    System.out.println("mask3Bit = " + Integer.toBinaryString(mask3Bit));

    int mask5Bit = 16; //binary rep: 10000
    System.out.println("mask5Bit = " + Integer.toBinaryString(mask5Bit));

    // now we'll create a mask that has all the bits on except the 3rd and 5th bit:
    int oppositeMask = -1;
    oppositeMask ^= mask3Bit;
    oppositeMask ^= mask5Bit;
    System.out.println("oppositeMask = " + Integer.toBinaryString(oppositeMask));

    //check if the 3rd bit is on:
    mask3Bit = number & mask3Bit;
    //shift twice to the right
    mask3Bit <<= 2;
    System.out.println("mask3Bit = " + Integer.toBinaryString(mask3Bit));
    //now do the same with the 5th bit
    //check if the 5th bit is on:
    mask5Bit = number & mask5Bit;
    //shift twice to the right
    mask5Bit >>= 2;
    System.out.println("mask5Bit = " + Integer.toBinaryString(mask5Bit));

    //now we'll turn off the 3rd and 5th bits in the original number
    number &= oppositeMask;
    System.out.println("number = " + Integer.toBinaryString(number));
    //and use the masks to switch the bits
    number |= mask3Bit;
    number |= mask5Bit;
    //let's check it out now:
    System.out.println("new number = " + Integer.toBinaryString(number));
```

OUTPUT:

```
number = 111
mask3Bit = 100
mask5Bit = 10000
oppositeMask = 11111111111111111111111111101011
mask3Bit = 10000
mask5Bit = 0 //here it's zero cause the original number has zero in the 5th bit and we used &. If the bit was on we would have gotten '100'
number = 11
new number = 10011
```

Comment: The byte converts it to decimal format, I want to use the bits at specific locations to perform required operations.

Comment: @chettyharish without seeing your code it's hard to provide more information than what I already did ;)

Comment: I don't have a code, as I don't know where to start. I have to code three binary data which keep shifting and the shift depends on specific bit values. Like lets say if 1st binary data has 1 at the 7th position, then it shifts twice.

Comment: my original comment still stands...

Comment: I tried redFive, but most just talk about shift operators. In one of my steps, I also have to change a specific bit like. 
X5=X1 XOR X2 XOR X3

Comment: @chettyharish here you go ;)